# Does anyone use ASPMaker?

Tags: asp.net, sql

Would you recommend using asp maker to create a website from a SQL database or is Visual Studio a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to say without knowing your requirements.

In general code generators like asp maker are designed to make certain types of apps and, if you need that type of app, they're great.

I would suggest downloading the trial and seeing if it meets your needs. Long term, you may be better off with a more general tool like Visual Studio (although you don't necessarily need visual studio to write ASP/ASP.net)

Also, keep in mind that classic ASP is somewhat outmoded; asp.net may be a better technology to focus your time and energy on (better community support, up-to-date tools etc)